# How to complete Wolf's Den mission?

Tags: far-cry-4

In the first mission (Wolf's Den), I have shot the barrel to blow up the den and skinned five wolves. However, the "wolf skins" counter still says "0/2". Are there special wolves that look different from the normal ones around the den, or am I experiencing a bug?

I have tried this mission three times now with no success. I've blown up the den first and skinned the wolves first. :( I'm playing the PC version.

Comment: Did you use the bow?

Comment: Yes, I used the bow for the wolves and even to blow up the barrel and destroy the den.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you begin the mission, you should encounter about 2 wolves on your way to the den. At the den entrance I believe there is one or two wolves outside and one inside.

I suggest you kill all the wolves before hitting the red explosive barrels. Perhaps a bug occurs when you destroy the den before clearing it, thus there might still be one wolf alive within the then.

Aim for the head with your arrows. You should get two skins per *clean kill*.

If after another try it's still not working, you might want to check for your game's file integrity on Steam to make sure nothing's corrupted/broken.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried killing all the wolves (including the one inside) before blowing up the den on one of my attempts, but I'll give that another go.

Comment: I started back at the village when I reloaded, and I followed the same path I had done twice before: kill wolves and then blow the den. This time, however, the first wolf I killed (thanks for the *clean kill* tip) netted me two skins. I think it was just bugged because it wasn't restarting at the village.

Answer (score 1):

The above advice is a fruitless goose chase.The reason you cannot collect enough skins is because you only have two bait bags.  You need to upgrade them.  You need to go into crafting to do this.   Do that and collect skins of the wolves you kill until your bags are full.  Blow up the cave and get on the quad bike and return to camp.  Tips:  at the start throw away the wooden arrows and collect the metal ones in the ground store near the old lady, they are more powerful.   Also if you get an instant kill you get two wolves skins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it wouldn't show 2/2 skins after trying lots of combinations like ones listed in the first post.

> I completed it by **blowing up the cave first** and then skinning the
>   two wolves that were already dead outside the cave.
>
> Those two dead wolves will be glowing like other objects in the game
>   that can be used/picked up. I didn't shoot or bother any of the living
>   wolves.

Ok if you try it that way you may not survive attacks by the wolves as you proceed!

**So then try killing the wolves if you have to but don't skin them, just skin the two already dead ones in the grass outside the cave. That's after you collapse the cave.**

Comment: Interesting. I did notice some wolves outside the den were already dead. I'll try this out, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the bow you receive on that mission in order for the skin counter to go up. So the issue may be that you killed the wolves with another weapon, besides your bow, and because of that, the game doesn't register the skins you get from killing them.

Comment: I received the bow in the village before riding the ATV to the mission. I did find the goodies hidden under the hut behind the woman who ignores you. I'll search there again to see if there's a different bow to use.